# how to connect php, MySQL with android through xampp?

Tags: android, database, xampp, android-webservice

I am a newbie in android and working on an app. I will be using a database on a server but meanwhile I have created a database on xampp and followed [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) link to connect my app with the database. I am trying to register a user and store his details into my db. I have created 3 files in xampp/htdocs folder: Config.php , DbConnect.php and new_user.php to add a new user into the database.
I am using the

```
url_create_product = "http://localhost/Signup_api/new_user.php"
```

where Signup_api is my folder in xampp/htdocs.
I have also created a JSONParser.java file in my src folder along with main activity.
But the app shows "Creating product.." message for a few minutes and then stops.
Has anyone tried to connect android app to xampp before? Please share your experience. Is it necessary to use wamp?

Comment: Doesn't matter what kind of server you use. What did you change that the androidhive example doesn't work?

Comment: I changed the url because I wanted to connect app with my database. I have 10 fields in my db table so I made changes in the create_product.php to accept 10 entries instead of 3. In android src folder I have made only NewProductActivity.java to add a new user, and JSONParser.java as it is. I think the problem is with the url. I used my IP address, and 10.0.2.2 but it doesn't work.

Comment: also i have used spinners to input data instead of editText in my android code.

Comment: You changed so much and you have so many files. Then you cannot tell us if it is a connection problem or wrong code. So there is a lot to find out. Lets start with one php file which you try to call with your android client. Post code of the client posting/getting the php file.

Answer (score 1):

use ip address instead of localhost ... Example http://locahost/xxxx/index.php will be http://192.x.x.x/..../index.php. Test on android browser it can access or not first.